# Trying to get guild from channel id

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've tried this code:

```
module.exports = async (client, channel) => {
  if (channel.type === "dm" || channel.type === "group") return;

  var guild;
  client.guilds.forEach(e => {
    e.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'CHANNEL_DELETE'})
      .then(audit => {
        if (audit.entries.first().id === channel.id) guild = e;
      });
  });
  if (!guild) return;
};
```

I am wanting to get the guild of the channel id that is passed on through the event parameters.
This is in **channelDelete** event, so I can't do `client.channels.get(channel.id)` since the ID does not exist in that collection. I need to get the information from the audit logs.

The problem is that I feel like this is overdoing the API, or there is probably a better method instead of having to loop through every single guild this bot is in.

Also, the actual code does not work as intended. It seems as though it reaches `if (!guild) return;` before the actual loops have finished, which means it will always return.

So, how do I make it so the code flows step by step, so that it does not return all the time, or a way to improve the code where it is not as intensive (if this method is intensive on the API/host).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply reference [`channel.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=guild) instead of trying to acquire the guild from the client's cache.

For future reference, to skip a value in a loop, you should use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) rather than `return`.